# What are the probabilities of receiving each of the crew types in the World of Warcraft garrison shipyard?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm having a tough time finding any info about the probabilities of each of the different crew types for the garrison shipyard. I'm trying to build a destroyer with a human crew to round out my fleet by following this guide: http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1913571-Naval-Fleet-to-counter-all-missions-with-gt-90-Chance (specifically fleet #1)

So far I'm 0 for 26 in building a destroyer with a human crew. Got the Murloc crew on the second try, and since then it's been everything but human. I would have thought the Murloc crew would be the tough one to get...

Does anyone know what the probabilities are for each of the crew types?

Answer (score 3):

The probabilities for each factional crew type are exactly equal (one in seven). It's just RNG.

There are 20 possible Destroyers* and 20 possible Submarines, according to Wowhead, and while only one of each can roll Murloc (Mrgrggrgl Mark III and Brgrggrgl Mark II), the Murloc ships are guaranteed that particular crew. So. for those particular varieties of ship, there's a roughly 5% chance of getting a Murloc crew. Any other ship will randomly roll a factional race, and there's no correlation between the names and who's running them (my carrier, "Pact of the Val'kyr", laughably has a Tauren crew).

*The Awakener is the 21st Destroyer but as it's a prefab ship only and comes with an Arakkoa crew, it's not relevant here.

Many things in WoW are artifacts of using the same RNG for many millions of players, so outliers will crop up and frustrate people.

Comment: Is that backed up by a blue post, release notes, or testing with a statistically significant sample size? Not doubting you, but if there's a link with such info it would be good to add that to the answer...

Comment: Definitely wasn't addressed by blues or patch notes. My only source is combing through both my own characters and those of many, many people on the forums posting their current collections.